# Number of primitive characters modulo $m$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $N(m)$ be the number of primitive Dirichlet characters modulo $m$.
Could someone please explain me why it satisfies the following relation?:
$$
\phi(m) = \sum_{d|m} N(d).
$$

Thank you very much!

Here, $\phi$ is the Euler totient function.

Comment: One solution is that, if $\gcd(m_1,m_2)=1$ then $N(m_1m_2)=N(m_1)N(m_2)$ and if $p$ is a prime then $n(p)=p-2$ and $n(p^r)=(p-1)^2p^{r-2}$. So you have first to prove the statement for powers of primes and then extend it by multiplicativity

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** (maybe not the best solution)

First you can prove that if $\gcd(m1,m2)=1$ then $N(m_1m_2)=N(m_1)N(m_2)$ and if $p$ is a prime then $N(p)=p−2$ and $N(p^r)=(p−1)^2p^{r−2}$. So you can first prove the statement for powers of primes, and complete the proof using the miltiplicativity of $N$.

Let me know if you succeeded

Answer (score 2):

The RHS counts the number of Dirichlet characters modulo $m$ (primitive or not) because each Dirichlet character mod $m$ is induced by a unique primitive Dirichlet character mod $d$ for some (uniquely determined) $d \mid m$.

Hence it suffices to show that there are $\varphi(m)$ Dirichlet characters mod $m$. This is indeed the case, because the group Dirichlet characters mod $m$ may be identified with the dual group of $(\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z)^\times$. Now for any finite abelian group $A$, the dual group $\widehat{A}$ is non-canonically isomorphic to $A$.

Comment: Thanks for adding this—the other answer is correct, but this is a much better solution.