# Deduce a formula for number of primitive character modulo $k$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Define $$F(k) = |\{g : g \ \mbox{is primitive characters modulo}\ k\}|.$$
I would like to calculate $F$, and fine its potential formula.I think for odd prime $p$, $$F(p) = 1.$$

I think if I can prove that $F$ is multiplicative, then it might be possible to find a formula. However, not sure if $F$ is multiplicative, or even $F$ is, I do not see a way to deduce the fact.

Comment: Do you mean [Dirichlet characters modulo $k$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/259725/what-are-dirichlet-characters)?

Comment: Actually $F(p)=p-2$ for odd $p$. Check here anyway: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1445345/number-of-primitive-characters-modulo-m

Comment: Yes, I mean Dirichlet character.

Comment: Oh, so I can deduce a formula using Mobius Inversion formula. Thank you for the info. Then what is left is to prove that it is multiplicative. I understand the gerneral method now, but any hints to prove multiplicativity ?